# I Downloaded a site and uploaded it in my test server. Functionality are working great but designs are not

Tags: php

I Downloaded a site and uploaded it in my test server. Functionality are working fine but designs are not....

How can i able to solve this... Kindly give me an idea to solve this issue..

Website developed using PHP

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Petrotta: When u see the above mentioned site you can able to understand what my problem is..

Comment: What, specifically, do you want to fix? I see differences, but no obvious failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are serving is not the same as Source Site page, there's all manner of differences.

Start with the stylesheets they are using: one has

```
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

the other

```
  <link href="skins/template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: You are right.. Mistake is mine.. I do changes in the wrong folder